# How to make fried beetroot chips

Tags: chips

How can we make crispy fried beetroot chips with a bright red color? I tried several times with or without maïzena in many different temperatures but the result was soft chips or chips with a dark brown color.

Comment: Never done it, but given the high sugar content and the presence of proteins as well, it would be difficult to avoid maillard browning which happens at around 140C but it can also occur at much lower rates at lower temperatures.

Comment: The only way to preserve the colour is by freeze drying which is hard to do in a home kitchen. A second best might be a food dehydrator. I would soak the slices in lemon juice or citric acid or vitamin C solution for a couple of minutes before drying. Set the air temperature low.

Comment: how 'bout baking them up ? use a mandoline and bake them up ?

Comment: Aren't beetroot generally purple?

Comment: Could you clarify, please: Does baking in an oven count as "frying" for you?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this qualifies for an answer since I had never done beetroot chips. If not I would be happy to remove it.

I had success with parsnip and apple chips:

- dip in 65°C dilute citric acid solution for 2-3 minutes (inhibits maillard), diluted vinegar or lemon juice works too
- dry chips well on kitchen towel and place neatly on an oven tray without overlapping
- put onto the lowest rack in a fan oven at the lowest temperature (<100°C)
- bake overnight for 8-12 hours

Comment: Ok, these are supposed to bullet points, right? (Use a space after the `-` so Markdown will properly recognise it.) I actually though a bit about how the hell a -65°C citric acid bath is supposed to work...

Comment: sorry about both formatting and lack of explanation in the first step